# ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'some values"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using `sklearn.LabelEncoder` to convert my categorical data into numerical for proper model fitting, but when I apply it on this I get this error

> ValueError: y contains previously unseen labels: 'Wilkes, Mrs. James
>   (Ellen Needs)'

The categorical columns in train and test data are same.

Anybody who can tell me whats the problem?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
train_data.fillna(0)
s= (train_data.dtypes == 'object')
object_cols = list(s[s].index)
label_train_data=train_data.copy()
label_test_data=test_data.copy()
Label_encoder=LabelEncoder()
for col in object_cols:
  label_train_data[col]=Label_encoder.fit_transform(train_data[col])
  label_test_data[col]=Label_encoder.transform(test_data[col])
```

Comment: You should give more details, at least which line triggers the error; maybe some context. Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `LabelEncoder()` is meant for target variable. It looks to me that you are using that for input data. I guess `OrdinalEncoder()` would meet your requirement of converting objects to numeric.

Regarding your error,

Some values in the test data fields / columns are not present in the training data hence `ordinalEnconder` does not know how to encode them.